# Android Map is not showing in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am following this tutoial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

I am 100% sure that I did everything the same, the app works fine but my problem is I can not see the map, I've worked with Google map before and I am 100% sure from api key for the map.

I can only see the grid lines and the places positions when i open the map

this how the map looks like in my app
http://im57.gulfup.com/i195l.png

Comment: Post your manifest file.

Comment: are there any errors in logcat.?

Comment: Please check this out. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score 3):

```
 public class map extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;
static double lat,lon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available   

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);               


         // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
    }

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();     
    lat=latitude;
    lon=longitude;
    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));        


    // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );      

}  

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have internet permission in your manifest? Apart from that you can follow below url for the same.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Hope this help you.